# sqlite file path created using iOS - UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

In my application we are currently using sqlite from `UIWebView` to store user preferences and details. Now we are moving this functionality in native Objective-C code, and want to preserve those defaults when application will be updated.

I am thinking of accessing .sqlite file from Objective-C code and transfer those preferences in `NSUserDefaults`. Where can I look for .sqlite files created by `UIWebView`, whats the default location ?

Comment: You must already know that as you need the path in order to open the sqlite database don't you?

Comment: You are right in case of Object-C code, I can specify path where I want to save .sqlite file but in case of UIWebView I can't specify path.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you.

Comment: In JavaScript code, sqlite path and access is managed by the browser and direct access to .sqlite file is not allowed. Whereas in Objective-C code we can specify path for .sqlite file. Does it make sense?

Comment: I think it's my lack of experience with `UIWebView` that is the issue here; ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the simulator, db files are here:

```
/Users/<your-user>/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/User/Applications/<your-app-id>/Library/WebKit/Databases/file__0/<database-name>
```

On the device, try:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/<your-app-id>/Library/WebKit/Databases/file__0/<database-name>
```

Comment: Here if I am running app in simulator path is following,
    /Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/iPhone\ Simulator/6.1/Applications/<app-id>/Library/Caches

Is it changed now ? Will be different for installed and sanboxed app ?

Comment: It may well have changed since iCloud was implemented yes. You could check the location using this desktop app to view files on your device: [http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)